# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Process unexpectedly closed with status: 0 (for GeckoDriver and Firefox 60.2.1esr)

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, geckodriver

I am struggling to find the correct selenium java and server versions for firefox 60.2.1esr or visa-versa . Test configuaration : geckodriver 0.22.0, WIN7 OS and testng 6.14.3, selenium(server and java) v3.14.0 and JDK 8u181 I receive error message like :

**

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Process unexpectedly closed with status: 0
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z'
System info: host: 'L02DI1744431DIT', ip: '10.136.32.140', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
remote stacktrace: stack backtrace:
   0:           0x4821c4 - <no info>
   1:           0x482933 - <no info>
   2:           0x445159 - <no info>
   3:           0x44c838 - <no info>
   4:           0x43026a - <no info>
   5:           0x40ba4e - <no info>
   6:           0x4119b9 - <no info>
   7:           0x6d2c89 - <no info>
   8:           0x426006 - <no info>
   9:           0x6cd490 - <no info>
  10:         0x773159cd - BaseThreadInitThunk
```

**

Could anyone please suggest me how to find solution?

Comment: What is your expected _Test Configuration_ ? Why not using _Selenium v3.14.0_?

Comment: Thanks , i will try with v3.14 and keep you posted

Comment: 'org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: permission denied
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z'
System info: host: 'L02DI1744431DIT', ip: '10.136.32.140', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_121''  , **This is the response for test configuration** (Testng 6.14.3, java 3.14.0 and server 3.14.0

Comment: If you can update the question with your exact requirement and this error trace log I will construct an answer for you.

Comment: @New contributor, I updated my question, please have a look

Comment: please show the code you are running and the full stacktrace and error message.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: permission denied Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z' System info: host: 'L02DI1744431DIT', ip: '10.136.32.140', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_121
```

...implies that the **WebDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **WebBrowser** session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- Though your *Selenium Client* version is **3.14.0**.
- Your *JDK version* is **1.8.0_121** which is pretty **ancient**.

### Solution

- Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels [**JDK 8u181**](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).

Comment: I really appreciate for your explanation. I will try on Monday and keep you posted

Comment: this answer appears to be a wild guess rather than an answer to the question asked.

Comment: **org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: permission denied
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z'
System info: host: 'L02DI1744431DIT', ip: '10.136.32.140', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver** I tried with JDK8U181 but the same issue faced. Actually selenium launches FF browser and then throws above error message. Any suggestions please ?

Comment: @Abdulhameed Can you update the question with your code trials and the full error stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone ran into this issue recently receiving the same error, I completed two checks on the server. First was to see if the test would run at all using the FF marionette. It did. The second check was to make sure FF ran on its own and it also did.

Back to Jenkins, rerunning the project it ran perfectly. I can only speculate that it had to have something to do with FF's automatic updates and it needing to run once(initialize itself) prior to the tests.

If you receive the **process unexpectedly closed with status 0**, make sure that first your test(s) have no errors and second that FF can run at all before you start digging around.